# When I send a socket request to nginx, the request from nginx is not balanced to socket server

Tags: java, sockets, nginx, socket.io, load-balancing

I’m setting up a socket server and socket client with java,and want to balance socket request with nginx load balancing.my problem is When I send a socket request to nginx, the request from nginx is not balanced to socket server.

my socket client code is :

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

/**
 * This class implements java socket client
 * @author pankaj
 *
 */
public class SocketClientExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException, InterruptedException{
        //get the localhost IP address, if server is running on some other IP, you need to use that
        InetAddress host = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        Socket socket = null;
        ObjectOutputStream oos = null;
        ObjectInputStream ois = null;
        for(int i=0; i<5;i++){
            //establish socket connection to server
            socket = new Socket("10.104.2.140", 9443);
            //write to socket using ObjectOutputStream
            oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            System.out.println("Sending request to Socket Server");
            if(i==4)oos.writeObject("exit");
            else oos.writeObject(""+i);
            //read the server response message
            ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            String message = (String) ois.readObject();
            System.out.println("Message: " + message);
            //close resources
            ois.close();
            oos.close();
            Thread.sleep(100);
        }
    }
}
```

my socket server is :

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.lang.ClassNotFoundException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

/**
 * This class implements java Socket server
 * @author pankaj
 *
 */
public class SocketServerExample {

    private static ServerSocket server;
    private static int port = 9876;

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException{
        server = new ServerSocket(port);
        while(true){
            System.out.println("Waiting for the client request");
            Socket socket = server.accept();
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            String message = (String) ois.readObject();
            System.out.println("Message Received: " + message);
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            oos.writeObject("Hi Client "+message);
            ois.close();
            oos.close();
            socket.close();
            if(message.equalsIgnoreCase("exit")) break;
        }
        System.out.println("Shutting down Socket server!!");
        server.close();
    }

}
```

my nginx configuration :

```
 upstream backend {
      ip_hash;
      server 10.104.2.140:9876;
   }
 server {

      listen 9443;

      location / {
        proxy_pass http://backend;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_http_version 1.1;

        add_header Set-Cookie cip=$upstream_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

      }
         location /nginx_status {
          stub_status on;
          access_log   off;
          allow  127.0.0.1;
         # deny all;
        }
   }
```

when i run socket client , 
My request is received by nginx but not sent to the socket server.i see my request in nginx access log.

this is my log request in nginx :

```
10.104.9.12 - - [14/Aug/2019:14:56:47 +0000] "\xAC\xED\x00\x05" 400 157 "-""--" "-"http_x_forwarded_for = -, real_ip_remote_addr = 10.104.9.12"--" "-"
```

and this is my log format in nginx :

```
'$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
 '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent '
 '"$http_referer"'
 '"--" "$http_user_agent"'
 'http_x_forwarded_for = $http_x_forwarded_for, '
 'real_ip_remote_addr = $realip_remote_addr'
 '"--" "$upstream_addr"';
```

Comment: could not find related documentation to point you out but it seems order matters inside location block of nginx. Can you try to put the `proxy_pass` line at the end of your location block after you have set all the headers ?

Comment: location  / {
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;


      proxy_redirect off;

      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_pass http://backend;
    }
this is not work again.

Comment: and what about your error.log?

Comment: Error.log is empty

Comment: in order to be loggged there `error_log` level must be `info`. Is that the case ?

Comment: this is error log in info :   2019/08/15 09:25:02 [info] 20571#20571: *2 client sent invalid method while reading client request line, client: 10.104.9.12, server: , request: "▒▒"
PuTTY2019/08/15 09:25:02 [info] 20571#20571: *2 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading client request line, client: 10.104.9.12, server: , request: "▒▒"
PuTTY

Comment: The error you are getting says that your client request is not valid. After reviewing a little bit your java client code, I don't think that you are using websocket protocol which you are trying to load balance from nginx side. You use normal sockets instead. For that you need to have a tcp stream balancing method.